# Call to a member function find() on array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
 "message": "Call to a member function find() on array",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
```

How do I get the id parameter from the array below: When i pass the parameter 1 i want to fetch only first element when id is 2 I fetch item 2 of array

```
  public function payments($id){
        $data = [
            ['id' => 1, 'amount' => '22000', 'name' => 'ken'],
            ['id' => 2, 'amount' => '24000', 'name' => 'ken'],
            ['id' => 3, 'amount' => '26000', 'name' => 'ken'],
            ['id' => 4, 'amount' => '2000', 'name' => 'tom'],
        ];

        return $data->find($id);
    }
```

Comment: `How do I get the id parameter from the array below:` There are 4 of them. What do you want your final array to look like or are you just trying to loop through them all?

Comment: i want to get id from url parameter and display specific item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function payments($id){
    $data = [
        ['id' => 1, 'amount' => '22000', 'name' => 'ken'],
        ['id' => 2, 'amount' => '24000', 'name' => 'ken'],
        ['id' => 3, 'amount' => '26000', 'name' => 'ken'],
        ['id' => 4, 'amount' => '2000', 'name' => 'tom'],
    ];
    $data = collect($data);
    return $data->where('id', $id)->all();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we're using a multi-dimensional array, we can use `array_search` with `array_column`.

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'amount' => '22000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 2, 'amount' => '24000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 3, 'amount' => '26000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 4, 'amount' => '2000', 'name' => 'tom'],
];
        
$key = array_search($id, array_column($data, 'id'));
echo var_dump($data[$key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "Laravel" alternative solution using collection

```
public function payments($id){
    $data = [
        ['id' => 1, 'amount' => '22000', 'name' => 'ken'],
        ['id' => 2, 'amount' => '24000', 'name' => 'ken'],
        ['id' => 3, 'amount' => '26000', 'name' => 'ken'],
        ['id' => 4, 'amount' => '2000', 'name' => 'tom'],
    ];
    $data = collect($data);
    return $data->where('id', $id)->first();
}
```